# What is delloc function used for does it run itself?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    // in case you have something to dealloc, do it in this method
    // in this particular example nothing needs to be released.
    // cocos2d will automatically release all the children (Label)
    [_targets release];
    [_projectiles release];
    [_nottargets release];
    [_helicopters release];
    [_Explosions release];
    [_GameChances release];

    _targets=nil;
    _projectiles = nil;
    _nottargets=nil;
    _helicopters=nil;
    _Explosions=nil;
    _GameChances=nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

I have this function, what is it used for?  Does it call itself automatically or do we have to call it at the end when we switch to another page?

Comment: Why, exactly, do you have this function if you don't understand it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gets called by the Objective c runtime when the retain count of an object goes to zero (during a release call). You can release the objects you own in your dealloc.

Comment: what do you mean by "when the retain count of object goes to zero"?or how to make it zero

Comment: You need to read about memory management for IOS here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Answer (score 0):

It would appear it releases memory that was allocated.  No, it does not automatically run itself, judging by the commented code you've given.

Comment: It's not a built in function rite?

Comment: It would appear it's not built-in, yes.